# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have shape (14,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I have an input like this

`x=[[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]....[n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n]]
x.shape=(18998,8)`

An output like this

`y= 11 11 11 11 ... 10
y.shape=(18998,)`

I build the model like this

```
env_model = Sequential()
env_model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', input_dim=8))
env_model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
env_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
env_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
env_model.add(Dense(14, activation='softmax'))
env_model.summary()
env_model.save('model_weights/weights.environment.h5')
```

I thought the model should not have been any issue, but I kept getting error like the following:

> 'ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have shape (14,) but got array with shape (1,)'

Could you help me to point out what is wrong with my input, output or model? I am looking forward to your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should use `keras.utils.to_categorical()` to convert a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model ,

```
env_model.add(Dense(14, activation='softmax'))
```

The Dense vector expects a target array of shape ( batch_size , 14 ). You are providing it a array of shape ( batch_size , ).

> Note : In the shape of a NumPy array the comma defines an unspecified dimension. Suppose you have an array of shape ( 12 , ). Meaning you have 12 samples of varying lengths (1 , 2 ,6 etc. ). The second dim is not specific and hence is shown by a `,`.

So, you need to convert your target data into shape ( 18998 , dim ) where dim is the length of the feature. To achieve you can try two approaches :

1. As mentioned by @giser_yugang, convert the target data into categorical data using `keras.utils.to_categorical()`
2. Pad the feature vector to a fixed length. You can do this by `keras.preprocessing.sequences.pad_sequence()`

**Hence, at final, you should have a fixed length target data.**